# Minifying scripts in Laravel Elixir by default

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

With Laravel Elixir when using `mix.scripts()` or `mix.babel()` the default behavior is to not minify unless the `--production` option is passed to `gulp`. Is it possible to reverse this and apply minification by default? Maybe even to disable it for one build from command line when it's really not needed?

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir#css-source-maps) mentions some way to configure Elixir, e.g., disable source maps, but I struggle to find a full list of configuration options...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
elixir.config.production = true;

elixir(function(mix) { ...
```

> Internally, Elixir defines the variable above to check the environment and modify the behaviour of certain recipes:

You could also maybe use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) npm package to achieve the reverse, e.g. `gulp --no-minify`

`gulpfile.js`:

```
...
var argv = require('yargs').argv
elixir.config.production = true;
if (argv['no-minify'] !== undefined) {
  elixir.config.production = false;
}
```

You can see the config source code here: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/src/Config.js for other options that you may want to change.

Hope this helps.